# Show $f: X\to Y$ maps set closed relatively to A, to sets closed relatively to $f(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Question: Let $X$ be a compact metric space and Y a metric space 
> Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$  be continuous and $A \subset X$ 
> Have $f(A^c) \subset (f(A))^c$
> Show $f$ maps set closed relatively to A, to  sets closed relatively to $f(A)$

Attempted Answer:
Consider a set $W$ that is  closed relative to A 
$W$ can be expressed as $A \cap V$ where $V$ is closed in X
$W^c$=$(A \cap V)^c$=$A^c \cup V^c$ 
$W$=$((W)^c)^c$
$F(A^c \cup V^c) \subset (f(W))^c$

I'm stuck here. I feel like $F^-1(W)$ is involved, but it's not clear to me The problem seems pretty easy, but I can't see a clear way forward. Could you please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting as you have, with $W$ closed relative to $A$, we let $W=V\cap A$ for closed (hence compact) $V$.  Then
$$f(V)=f(V\cap A)\cup f(V\cap A^c)=f(W)\cup f(V\cap A^c).$$

Therefore

\begin{align*}
f(V)\cap f(A) &=(f(W)\cup f(V\cap A^c))\cap f(A) \\
&=(f(W)\cap f(A))\cup (f(V\cap A^c)\cap f(A)) =f(W).
\end{align*}

Notice that the last equality follows since $W\subseteq A$, and since $f(A)\cap f(A^c)=\emptyset$.

Since $V$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, $f(V)$ is compact, hence closed, so the result follows.

##### Remark

The preceding arguments shows that the result is true whenever $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff (we used Hausdorff to get the fact that $f(V)$ is closed from the fact that it's compact).  No metric is required for either space.